# Why are multiplication and addition associative?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, intuition, math-history, real-numbers

Without workin in a rigorous formal system, how can one intuitively establish that multiplication and addition are associative operations on the real line (including negative numbers)?

Comment: Look into the development of the real numbers. You can more than likely find this in Rudin's book or lecture notes online. I don't mean to put off your question, but any answer to this will be one reciting exactly what comes from the sources mentioned (which you can just read for yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Let's use the following analogy for the multiplication case; suppose we have a block of wood in the corner of the room, dimensions $a \times b \times c$. It doesn't matter whether you lift the side with dimension $a \times b$ up $c$ or if you take a wood-line $a$ and have it fill out the area $b \times c$; it will fill the same volume. You can extend this to a single negative number if you "drill through walls" with a sort of wood-debt; multiple negatives will require a kind of checkerboard pattern for the corner of the room.

For addition, think of it like a line-map, and you are taking directions. It doesn't matter if you stop at $a$, sleep, and then go further $b + c$, versus stopping at $a + b$, sleep, then go further $c$. You'll end up at the same place, no matter what.

If you would like a more formal derivation, you'll probably want to have associativity of addition and multiplication for rational numbers, then derive the real numbers with your favorite method (Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences are two examples), and then find that associativity remains.

Comment: The author of the question seems to be confused by the term *line-map* (see [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/33115/2594)), and admittedly, I do not understand either what it is supposed to mean in this context. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Like a big paper road map, except instead of a giant piece of paper, it's a long line strip. So $a, b,$ and $c$ are all distances, which may even be negative.

Answer (score 0):

In a more general setting, associativity of addition is linked to Desargues' property. See for example (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6851)